# Assigning Variable to 2D Array From TreeView C#

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, multidimensional-array

I currently have a Windows Form I'm developing in Visual Studio. It has multiple text boxes, two buttons, and a `Treeview`. On this `Treeview`, there are multiple "Root" nodes and then those nodes have multiple "Child" nodes. I need to return each node that is checked by the user.

The idea I had was to use a 2D array and put the "Parent" node(s) in column 1 and their child(ren) in column 2,3,4 etc... (depending on how many children are checked).

The problem I'm having is that I can `MessageBox` each node that is checked correctly, but cannot assign that value to a position in the 2D array. See below for code and snippets of the form.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int a = 0;
        int b = 1;
        
            //downcause[a, a] = "test";
            MessageBox.Show(downcause[a, a]);
        
        foreach (TreeNode tn  in treeView1.Nodes)
        {                
            if (tn.Checked)
            {
                string holdparent = Convert.ToString(tn.Text);
                downcause[a, a] = Convert.ToString(tn.Text);
               
                MessageBox.Show(holdparent);
                MessageBox.Show("array - > ", downcause[a,a]);
                foreach (TreeNode child in tn.Nodes)
                {
                    if (child.Checked)
                    {                            
                        string holdchild = Convert.ToString(child.Text);
                        downcause[a, b] = holdparent;                            
                        MessageBox.Show(holdchild);
                        MessageBox.Show("array - > ", downcause[a, b]);
                        b++;
                    }
                }

                a++;
            }
        }   
    }
```

**Form with Treeview Nodes Selected**:

[image]

On Button Click, it's displaying the checked Parent Node:

[image]

When trying to output data in the 2d array, it's null:

[image]

Comment: Why are you trying to put the data into an array? How is `downcause` defined? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: If there is a better way, then I'm all ears.   "string[,] downcause = new string [16,16]" Downcause should be which ever node is checked, the idea is to push which every node(s) are checked into a field in my database which will be tied to a unique op key.

Comment: How many downtime causes are there? Are they fixed values or will the items (text) change based on some condition. Which database are you using? What is the table/column definition?

Comment: In total, there are 8 Parent downtime causes and each parent could have as many 6 children nodes. It just depends. I'm using a database on my SQL server. The column in the table will just be varchar(30). Looks like I'm just going to use 2 lists, one for the parent downtime cause and the other list for the children cause, and then just null out the child list when I move on to the next parent node selected if more than one is selected.

Comment: So you're planning to have a Table `DowntimeCause` that contains one or more downtime causes for a particular `opKey`? `DowntimeCause` perhaps has a composite primary key which is comprised of "OPKey", "MajorCause", "MinorCause" - where "OPKey" is also a foreign key?

Comment: I would just create classes: "Minor Stop", "Defects", etc... which contain the property name as a Boolean (ex: `public bool ToolBroke { get; set; } = false;`)  Then create another class that has an instance of each of these classes. For example: public class DowntimeCause { public MinorStopInfo MinorStop { get; set; } = new MinorStopInfo(); public DefectInfo Defect { get; set; } = new DefectInfo(); }

Comment: No, I have a table already made with primary and foreign keys. OP key is what the user will input, and then select their downtime which will then be pushed in the table in the record that matches the OP key that was inputted. I've got my SQL statements and all that, just need to figure out how to put the string values into my 2D array (if it's possible). If not, I can use my 2 lists. It's not ideal, but I can make it work. I like the idea of the classes, thank you @user9938 !!